# GitLabCI start build by commit hash or build id through API

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-7

Help me please. There is no answer at forums (( Can I retry build in GitlabCI through API? Retry build by commit hash at Gitlab or build id in GitlabCI. Like button pressed in GitlabCI web

I try to use commits api for init new build http://doc.gitlab.com/ci/api/commits.html, but i dont understand how to fill `data` object in json request.

Tell me please how to make build or rebuild by commit hash with GitlabCI REST API?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Use valid request to http://http://somegitlab/api/v1/commits?project_id=yourpojectId&project_token=yourproject token:
`{
    "data":{
      "before": "c3c39b43f160c2efed5bbc16d15e91eab3c2ec22",<-- not required
      "after": "5539ffc98f07777b6360e976cbc7a796bb61e315",
      "ref": "refs/heads/master",
      "commits": [{
            "id": "5539ffc98f07777b6360e976cbc7a796bb61e315",
            "message": "fixes #1 complete:1 and 3 sum output",  <-- not required
            "timestamp": "2011-12-12T14:27:31+02:00",           <-- not required
            "url": "http://somegitlab/sonmeproject/somecommit", <-- not required
            "author": {
                  "name": "Kirill Tilkachev",
                  "email": "lavcraft@gmail.com"
                }
            }
        ]
      }
}`